# Change Cons on Selected Option Association

Tags: javascript, api, url, constants, selection

I have the following Option select container that I would like to assign certain const values to:

```
<div class= "wrapper">
  <div class = "option-control">
<form>
  <h1> Please select a Servant class:</h1>
  <div class="box">
    Servant Class: <div class="inputWrap" class="input-field" id="subject">
      <select name="servant-class" type="option" class="servant-class">
                          <option value=""></option>
                          <option value="0" selected>Please select from the following...</option>
                         <option value="Archer" >Archer</option>
                             <option value="Saber" >Saber</option>
                        <option value="Lancer" >Lancer</option>
                          <option value="Rider" >Rider</option>
                          <option value="Caster" >Caster</option>
                          <option value="Assassin" >Assassin</option>
                          <option value="Berserker" >Berserker</option>
                          <option value="Ruler" >Ruler</option>
                          <option value="Avenger" >Avenger</option>
                          <option value="Moon Cancer" >Moon Cancer</option>
                          <option value="Alter Ego" >Alter Ego</option>
                          <option value="Foreigner" >Foreigner</option>
  
      </select></div><br>
```

For example, if option "Saber" is selected, I would like to then apply the const saberTitles to the URL map. If another const is selected, its corresponding const would be applied instead. Is this an If{} series of commands for URLs, or something else for the const of servantTitles? Please note that servantTitles represents the original test which will be replaced by my new function (if applicable).

```
const proxyurl = "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/";

const baseURL = 'https://fategrandorder.fandom.com/api.php';
const servantTitles = ['Artoria_Pendragon', 'Artoria_Pendragon_(Alter)', 'Artoria_Pendragon_(Lily)', 'Nero_Claudius', 'Siegfried', 'Gaius_Julius_Caesar', 'Altera', 'Gilles_de_Rais_(Saber)', "Chevalier_d'Eon", 'Okita_Sōji', 'Fergus_mac_Róich', 'Mordred', 'Nero_Claudius_(Bride)', 'Ryōgi_Shiki_(Saber)', 'Rama, Water_Iri', 'Lancelot_Saber', 'Gawain', 'Bedivere', 'Elizabeth_Báthory_(Brave)', 'Miyamoto_Musashi', 'Arthur_Pendragon_(Prototype)', 'Suzuka_Gozen', 'Frankenstein_(Saber)', 'Yagyū_Munenori', 'Sigurd', 'Medb_(Saber)', 'Diarmuid_Ua_Duibhne', 'Lanling_Wang', 'Beni-enma', 'Lakshmibai','Jason', 'Katsushika_Hokusai_(Saber)', 'Astolfo_(Saber)', 'Dioscuri', 'Tomoe_Gozen_(Saber)', 'Saitō_Hajime'];
const saberTitles = ['Artoria_Pendragon', 'Artoria_Pendragon_(Alter)', 'Artoria_Pendragon_(Lily)', 'Nero_Claudius', 'Siegfried', 'Gaius_Julius_Caesar', 'Altera', 'Gilles_de_Rais_(Saber)', "Chevalier_d'Eon", 'Okita_Sōji', 'Fergus_mac_Róich', 'Mordred', 'Nero_Claudius_(Bride)', 'Ryōgi_Shiki_(Saber)', 'Rama, Water_Iri', 'Lancelot_Saber', 'Gawain', 'Bedivere', 'Elizabeth_Báthory_(Brave)', 'Miyamoto_Musashi', 'Arthur_Pendragon_(Prototype)', 'Suzuka_Gozen', 'Frankenstein_(Saber)', 'Yagyū_Munenori', 'Sigurd', 'Medb_(Saber)', 'Diarmuid_Ua_Duibhne', 'Lanling_Wang', 'Beni-enma', 'Lakshmibai','Jason', 'Katsushika_Hokusai_(Saber)', 'Astolfo_(Saber)', 'Dioscuri', 'Tomoe_Gozen_(Saber)', 'Saitō_Hajime'];
const archerTitles = ['EMIYA', 'Gilgamesh', 'Robin_Hood', 'Atalanta', 'Euryale', 'Arash', 'Orion', 'David', 'Oda_Nobunaga', 'Nikola_Tesla', 'Arjuna', 'Kid_Gil', 'Billy_the_Kid', 'Tristan', 'Tawara_Tōta', 'Artoria_Pendragon_(Archer)', 'Anne_Bonny_&_Mary_Read_(Archer)', 'Chloe_von_Einzbern', 'Ishtar', 'James_Moriarty', 'EMIYA_(Alter)', 'Helena_Blavatsky_(Archer)', 'Tomoe_Gozen', 'Attila_the_San(ta)', 'Asagami_Fujino', 'Chiron', 'Napoléon', "Jeanne_d'Arc_(Archer)", 'William_Tell', 'Aśvatthāman', 'Paris', 'Osakabehime_(Archer)', 'Calamity_Jane', 'Nightingale_(Santa)', 'Sei_Shōnagon', 'Illyasviel_von_Einzbern_(Archer)', 'Oda_Nobukatsu'];
const lancerTitles = ['Cú_Chulainn', 'Elizabeth_Báthory','Musashibō_Benkei', 'Cú_Chulainn_(Prototype)', 'Leonidas_I', 'Romulus', 'Hector', 'Scáthach', 'Diarmuid_Ua_Duibhne', 'Artoria_Pendragon_(Lancer_Alter)', 'Karna', 'Fionn_mac_Cumhaill', 'Brynhildr', 'Li_Shuwen_(Lancer)',  'Artoria_Pendragon_(Lancer)', 'Tamamo_no_Mae_(Lancer)', 'Kiyohime_(Lancer)', 'Vlad_III_(EXTRA)', "Jeanne_d'Arc_(Alter)_(Santa_Lily)", 'Enkidu', 'Medusa_(Lancer)', 'Jaguar_Man', 'Minamoto_no_Raikō_(Lancer)', 'Parvati', 'Hōzōin_Inshun', 'Nezha', 'Ereshkigal', 'Valkyrie    Ibaraki_Dōji_(Lancer)', 'Qin_Liangyu', 'Bradamante', 'Nagao_Kagetora', 'Gareth', 'Mysterious_Alter_Ego_Λ', 'Caenis', 'Romulus-Quirinus', 'Utsumi_Erice', 'Consort_Yu_(Lancer)'];
const riderTitles = ['Medusa', 'Georgios', 'Edward_Teach', 'Boudica','Ushiwakamaru', 'Alexander', 'Marie_Antoinette', 'Martha   Francis_Drake', 'Anne_Bonny_&_Mary_Read', 'Artoria_Pendragon_(Santa_Alter)', 'Astolfo', 'Medb', 'Iskandar', 'Sakata_Kintoki_(Rider)', 'Ozymandias', 'Mordred_(Rider)', 'Quetzalcoatl', 'Christopher_Columbus', 'Artoria_Pendragon_(Rider_Alter)', 'Ishtar_(Rider)', 'Ivan_the_Terrible', 'Achilles', 'Sakamoto_Ryōma', 'Red_Hare', 'Sima_Yi_(Reines)', 'Leonardo_Da_Vinci_(Rider)', 'Bartholomew_Roberts', 'Carmilla_(Rider)', 'Mandricardo', 'Europa', 'Odysseus', 'Murasaki_Shikibu_(Rider)', 'Nemo'];
const assassinTitles = ['Sasaki_Kojirō', 'Hassan_of_the_Cursed_Arm', 'Stheno', 'Jing_Ke', 'Charles-Henri_Sanson', 'Phantom_of_the_Opera','Mata_Hari', 'Carmilla', 'Jack_the_Ripper', 'Henry_Jekyll_&_Hyde', 'Mysterious_Heroine_X', 'Ryōgi_Shiki_(Assassin)', 'EMIYA_(Assassin)', 'Hassan_of_the_Hundred_Faces', 'Shuten_Dōji', 'Fūma_Kotarō', 'Hassan_of_the_Serenity', 'Scáthach_(Assassin)', 'Cleopatra', '"The_Old_Man_of_the_Mountain"', 'Yan_Qing', 'Wu_Zetian', 'Nitocris_(Assassin)', 'Mochizuki_Chiyome', 'Katō_Danzō', 'Osakabehime', 'Semiramis', 'Okada_Izō', 'Ushiwakamaru_(Assassin)', 'Consort_Yu', 'Li_Shuwen', 'Kama', 'Gray', 'Charlotte_Corday', 'Okita_J_Sōji'];
const casterTitles = ['Medea', 'Gilles_de_Rais', 'Hans_Christian_Andersen', 'William_Shakespeare', 'Mephistopheles', 'Wolfgang_Amadeus_Mozart', 'Zhuge_Liang_(Lord_El-Melloi_II)', 'Cú_Chulainn_(Caster)', 'Elizabeth_Báthory_(Halloween)', 'Tamamo_no_Mae', 'Medea_(Lily)', 'Nursery_Rhyme', 'Paracelsus_von_Hohenheim', 'Charles_Babbage', 'Solomon', 'Helena_Blavatsky', 'Thomas_Edison', 'Geronimo', 'Irisviel_(Dress_of_Heaven)', 'Xuanzang_Sanzang', 'Nitocris', 'Leonardo_Da_Vinci', 'Marie_Antoinette_(Caster)', 'Illyasviel_von_Einzbern', 'Gilgamesh_(Caster)', 'Merlin', 'Solomon', 'Scheherazade', 'Nero_Claudius_(Caster)', 'Circe', 'Sieg', 'Queen_of_Sheba', 'Anastasia_Nikolaevna_Romanova', 'Avicebron', 'Scáthach-Skaði', 'Shuten_Dōji_(Caster)', 'Miyu_Edelfelt', 'Murasaki_Shikibu', 'Asclepius', 'Chen_Gong', 'Artoria_Caster'];
const berserkerTitles = ['Heracles', 'Lancelot', 'Lu_Bu_Fengxian', 'Spartacus', 'Sakata_Kintoki', 'Vlad_III', 'Asterios', 'Caligula Darius_III', 'Kiyohime', 'Eric_Bloodaxe','Tamamo_Cat', 'Frankenstein', 'Beowulf', 'Nightingale', 'Cú_Chulainn_(Alter)', 'Minamoto_no_Raikō', 'Ibaraki_Dōji', 'Mysterious_Heroine_X_(Alter)','Hijikata_Toshizō', 'Chacha', 'Penthesilea', 'Paul_Bunyan', 'Oda_Nobunaga_(Berserker)', 'Atalanta_(Alter)', "Jeanne_d'Arc_(Berserker_Alter)", 'Xiang_Yu', 'Arjuna_(Alter)', 'Mori_Nagayoshi', 'Salome','Miyamoto_Musashi_(Berserker)', 'Kijyo_Kōyō', 'Brynhildr_(Berserker)'];
const rulerTitles = ["Jeanne_d'Arc",'Amakusa_Shirō', 'Martha_(Ruler)', 'Sherlock_Holmes', 'Shi_Huang_Di', 'Quetzalcoatl_(Samba/Santa)', 'Astraea    Artoria_Pendragon_(Ruler)', 'Himiko'];
const avengerTitles = ['Edmond_Dantès', "Jeanne_d'Arc_(Alter)", 'Angra_Mainyu', 'Gorgon', 'Hessian_Lobo', 'Antonio_Salieri', 'Demon_King_Nobunaga', 'Space_Ishtar'];
const alteregoTitles = ['Meltlilith','Passionlip', 'Sesshōin_Kiara', 'Mecha_Eli-chan', 'Mecha_Eli-chan_MkII', 'Okita_Sōji_(Alter)', 'Sitonai', 'Kingprotea'];
const mooncancerTitles = ['BB','BB_(Summer)', 'Great_Statue_God', 'Sesshōin_Kiara_(Moon_Cancer)'];
const foreignerTitles = ['Abigail_Williams', 'Katsushika_Hokusai', 'Mysterious_Heroine_XX', 'Yang_Guifei', 'Voyager', 'Abigail_Williams_(Summer)', 'Van_Gogh'];


const URLs = servantTitles.map(title => `${proxyurl}${baseURL}?action=query&prop=revisions&titles=${title}&rvprop=content&format=json&origin=*`);
```

Comment: A much more reasonable structure would be to have one object that has the titles as keys (`const titles = { servant: [...], saber: [...], ... }`) and then to through `titles[foo].map(...` where the variable `foo` contains the title name.

Comment: @GuyIncognito I am incredibly new to Javascript and have only just now heard about foo from you. How would this link back to the option selection?

Comment: ...it's just a random placeholder name. You'll have to google how to get the value of currently selected option, it's not hard to find.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably change the way you store your data. You can store the titles in an object, where the keys are your "categories" (servant, saber, etc.), and the values are the arrays. You should also match these keys to your `option`'s `value`s. Instead of `<option value="Alter Ego">Alter Ego`, use `<option value="alterego">Alter Ego`.

In a JS object you can easily get an item value by its key. E.g., if
`const obj = {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}` and `const selected = 'b'`, then `obj[selected]` will return `2`, because the value of `selected` is `b`.

To listen to input changes, you can add an event listener to your `select` element, and whenever something new is selected, update the titles.

`element.addEventListener()` accepts a callback where you can grab the selected `option`'s value. Once you know this value, you can use it as the key in your `titles` object.

Check the snippet below:

```js
const proxyurl = 'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/';
const baseURL = 'https://fategrandorder.fandom.com/api.php';
const titles = {
  servant: ['Artoria_Pendragon', 'Artoria_Pendragon_(Alter)', 'Artoria_Pendragon_(Lily)', 'Nero_Claudius', 'Siegfried', 'Gaius_Julius_Caesar', 'Altera', 'Gilles_de_Rais_(Saber)', "Chevalier_d'Eon", 'Okita_Sōji', 'Fergus_mac_Róich', 'Mordred', 'Nero_Claudius_(Bride)', 'Ryōgi_Shiki_(Saber)', 'Rama, Water_Iri', 'Lancelot_Saber', 'Gawain', 'Bedivere', 'Elizabeth_Báthory_(Brave)', 'Miyamoto_Musashi', 'Arthur_Pendragon_(Prototype)', 'Suzuka_Gozen', 'Frankenstein_(Saber)', 'Yagyū_Munenori', 'Sigurd', 'Medb_(Saber)', 'Diarmuid_Ua_Duibhne', 'Lanling_Wang', 'Beni-enma', 'Lakshmibai', 'Jason', 'Katsushika_Hokusai_(Saber)', 'Astolfo_(Saber)', 'Dioscuri', 'Tomoe_Gozen_(Saber)', 'Saitō_Hajime'],
  saber: ['Artoria_Pendragon', 'Artoria_Pendragon_(Alter)', 'Artoria_Pendragon_(Lily)', 'Nero_Claudius', 'Siegfried', 'Gaius_Julius_Caesar', 'Altera', 'Gilles_de_Rais_(Saber)', "Chevalier_d'Eon", 'Okita_Sōji', 'Fergus_mac_Róich', 'Mordred', 'Nero_Claudius_(Bride)', 'Ryōgi_Shiki_(Saber)', 'Rama, Water_Iri', 'Lancelot_Saber', 'Gawain', 'Bedivere', 'Elizabeth_Báthory_(Brave)', 'Miyamoto_Musashi', 'Arthur_Pendragon_(Prototype)', 'Suzuka_Gozen', 'Frankenstein_(Saber)', 'Yagyū_Munenori', 'Sigurd', 'Medb_(Saber)', 'Diarmuid_Ua_Duibhne', 'Lanling_Wang', 'Beni-enma', 'Lakshmibai', 'Jason', 'Katsushika_Hokusai_(Saber)', 'Astolfo_(Saber)', 'Dioscuri', 'Tomoe_Gozen_(Saber)', 'Saitō_Hajime'],
  archer: ['EMIYA', 'Gilgamesh', 'Robin_Hood', 'Atalanta', 'Euryale', 'Arash', 'Orion', 'David', 'Oda_Nobunaga', 'Nikola_Tesla', 'Arjuna', 'Kid_Gil', 'Billy_the_Kid', 'Tristan', 'Tawara_Tōta', 'Artoria_Pendragon_(Archer)', 'Anne_Bonny_&_Mary_Read_(Archer)', 'Chloe_von_Einzbern', 'Ishtar', 'James_Moriarty', 'EMIYA_(Alter)', 'Helena_Blavatsky_(Archer)', 'Tomoe_Gozen', 'Attila_the_San(ta)', 'Asagami_Fujino', 'Chiron', 'Napoléon', "Jeanne_d'Arc_(Archer)", 'William_Tell', 'Aśvatthāman', 'Paris', 'Osakabehime_(Archer)', 'Calamity_Jane', 'Nightingale_(Santa)', 'Sei_Shōnagon', 'Illyasviel_von_Einzbern_(Archer)', 'Oda_Nobukatsu'],
  lancer: ['Cú_Chulainn', 'Elizabeth_Báthory', 'Musashibō_Benkei', 'Cú_Chulainn_(Prototype)', 'Leonidas_I', 'Romulus', 'Hector', 'Scáthach', 'Diarmuid_Ua_Duibhne', 'Artoria_Pendragon_(Lancer_Alter)', 'Karna', 'Fionn_mac_Cumhaill', 'Brynhildr', 'Li_Shuwen_(Lancer)', 'Artoria_Pendragon_(Lancer)', 'Tamamo_no_Mae_(Lancer)', 'Kiyohime_(Lancer)', 'Vlad_III_(EXTRA)', "Jeanne_d'Arc_(Alter)_(Santa_Lily)", 'Enkidu', 'Medusa_(Lancer)', 'Jaguar_Man', 'Minamoto_no_Raikō_(Lancer)', 'Parvati', 'Hōzōin_Inshun', 'Nezha', 'Ereshkigal', 'Valkyrie    Ibaraki_Dōji_(Lancer)', 'Qin_Liangyu', 'Bradamante', 'Nagao_Kagetora', 'Gareth', 'Mysterious_Alter_Ego_Λ', 'Caenis', 'Romulus-Quirinus', 'Utsumi_Erice', 'Consort_Yu_(Lancer)'],
  rider: ['Medusa', 'Georgios', 'Edward_Teach', 'Boudica', 'Ushiwakamaru', 'Alexander', 'Marie_Antoinette', 'Martha   Francis_Drake', 'Anne_Bonny_&_Mary_Read', 'Artoria_Pendragon_(Santa_Alter)', 'Astolfo', 'Medb', 'Iskandar', 'Sakata_Kintoki_(Rider)', 'Ozymandias', 'Mordred_(Rider)', 'Quetzalcoatl', 'Christopher_Columbus', 'Artoria_Pendragon_(Rider_Alter)', 'Ishtar_(Rider)', 'Ivan_the_Terrible', 'Achilles', 'Sakamoto_Ryōma', 'Red_Hare', 'Sima_Yi_(Reines)', 'Leonardo_Da_Vinci_(Rider)', 'Bartholomew_Roberts', 'Carmilla_(Rider)', 'Mandricardo', 'Europa', 'Odysseus', 'Murasaki_Shikibu_(Rider)', 'Nemo'],
  assassin: ['Sasaki_Kojirō', 'Hassan_of_the_Cursed_Arm', 'Stheno', 'Jing_Ke', 'Charles-Henri_Sanson', 'Phantom_of_the_Opera', 'Mata_Hari', 'Carmilla', 'Jack_the_Ripper', 'Henry_Jekyll_&_Hyde', 'Mysterious_Heroine_X', 'Ryōgi_Shiki_(Assassin)', 'EMIYA_(Assassin)', 'Hassan_of_the_Hundred_Faces', 'Shuten_Dōji', 'Fūma_Kotarō', 'Hassan_of_the_Serenity', 'Scáthach_(Assassin)', 'Cleopatra', '"The_Old_Man_of_the_Mountain"', 'Yan_Qing', 'Wu_Zetian', 'Nitocris_(Assassin)', 'Mochizuki_Chiyome', 'Katō_Danzō', 'Osakabehime', 'Semiramis', 'Okada_Izō', 'Ushiwakamaru_(Assassin)', 'Consort_Yu', 'Li_Shuwen', 'Kama', 'Gray', 'Charlotte_Corday', 'Okita_J_Sōji'],
  caster: ['Medea', 'Gilles_de_Rais', 'Hans_Christian_Andersen', 'William_Shakespeare', 'Mephistopheles', 'Wolfgang_Amadeus_Mozart', 'Zhuge_Liang_(Lord_El-Melloi_II)', 'Cú_Chulainn_(Caster)', 'Elizabeth_Báthory_(Halloween)', 'Tamamo_no_Mae', 'Medea_(Lily)', 'Nursery_Rhyme', 'Paracelsus_von_Hohenheim', 'Charles_Babbage', 'Solomon', 'Helena_Blavatsky', 'Thomas_Edison', 'Geronimo', 'Irisviel_(Dress_of_Heaven)', 'Xuanzang_Sanzang', 'Nitocris', 'Leonardo_Da_Vinci', 'Marie_Antoinette_(Caster)', 'Illyasviel_von_Einzbern', 'Gilgamesh_(Caster)', 'Merlin', 'Solomon', 'Scheherazade', 'Nero_Claudius_(Caster)', 'Circe', 'Sieg', 'Queen_of_Sheba', 'Anastasia_Nikolaevna_Romanova', 'Avicebron', 'Scáthach-Skaði', 'Shuten_Dōji_(Caster)', 'Miyu_Edelfelt', 'Murasaki_Shikibu', 'Asclepius', 'Chen_Gong', 'Artoria_Caster'],
  berserker: ['Heracles', 'Lancelot', 'Lu_Bu_Fengxian', 'Spartacus', 'Sakata_Kintoki', 'Vlad_III', 'Asterios', 'Caligula Darius_III', 'Kiyohime', 'Eric_Bloodaxe', 'Tamamo_Cat', 'Frankenstein', 'Beowulf', 'Nightingale', 'Cú_Chulainn_(Alter)', 'Minamoto_no_Raikō', 'Ibaraki_Dōji', 'Mysterious_Heroine_X_(Alter)', 'Hijikata_Toshizō', 'Chacha', 'Penthesilea', 'Paul_Bunyan', 'Oda_Nobunaga_(Berserker)', 'Atalanta_(Alter)', "Jeanne_d'Arc_(Berserker_Alter)", 'Xiang_Yu', 'Arjuna_(Alter)', 'Mori_Nagayoshi', 'Salome', 'Miyamoto_Musashi_(Berserker)', 'Kijyo_Kōyō', 'Brynhildr_(Berserker)'],
  ruler: ["Jeanne_d'Arc", 'Amakusa_Shirō', 'Martha_(Ruler)', 'Sherlock_Holmes', 'Shi_Huang_Di', 'Quetzalcoatl_(Samba/Santa)', 'Astraea    Artoria_Pendragon_(Ruler)', 'Himiko'],
  avenger: ['Edmond_Dantès', "Jeanne_d'Arc_(Alter)", 'Angra_Mainyu', 'Gorgon', 'Hessian_Lobo', 'Antonio_Salieri', 'Demon_King_Nobunaga', 'Space_Ishtar'],
  alterego: ['Meltlilith', 'Passionlip', 'Sesshōin_Kiara', 'Mecha_Eli-chan', 'Mecha_Eli-chan_MkII', 'Okita_Sōji_(Alter)', 'Sitonai', 'Kingprotea'],
  mooncancer: ['BB', 'BB_(Summer)', 'Great_Statue_God', 'Sesshōin_Kiara_(Moon_Cancer)'],
  foreigner: ['Abigail_Williams', 'Katsushika_Hokusai', 'Mysterious_Heroine_XX', 'Yang_Guifei', 'Voyager', 'Abigail_Williams_(Summer)', 'Van_Gogh'],
}

function getURLs(titles) {
  return titles.map(title => `${proxyurl}${baseURL}?action=query&prop=revisions&titles=${title}&rvprop=content&format=json&origin=*`);
}

document
  .querySelector('select')
  .addEventListener('change', function(event) {
    const { value } = event.target;
    
    if (!value) {
      console.log('No option selected');
      return;
    }

    const selected = titles[value];
    console.log(getURLs(selected));
  });
```

```html
<form>
  <h1> Please select a Servant class:</h1>
  <div class="box">
    Servant Class:
    <div class="inputWrap" class="input-field" id="subject">
      <select name="servant-class" type="option" class="servant-class">
        <option value="" selected>Please select from the following...</option>
        <option value="archer">Archer</option>
        <option value="saber">Saber</option>
        <option value="lancer">Lancer</option>
        <option value="rider">Rider</option>
        <option value="caster">Caster</option>
        <option value="assassin">Assassin</option>
        <option value="berserker">Berserker</option>
        <option value="ruler">Ruler</option>
        <option value="avenger">Avenger</option>
        <option value="mooncancer">Moon Cancer</option>
        <option value="alterego">Alter Ego</option>
        <option value="foreigner">Foreigner</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```